# Какие тест фреймворки нормально настраиваются и работают в WebStorm 11 под Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, test-driven-development

Доброго дня, уважаемые гуру веба. подскажите, пожалуйста какие из тест-фреймворков могут быть нормально установлены в WebStorm 11 под Ubuntu 14.04? Пытаюсь настроить mocha, но постоянно приходится наталкиватся на глюки и грабли в официальной документации, когда предлагаемый там путь ведет в тупик

Comment: Мне кажется что никто не использует встроенные возможности продуктов JetBrains, они ведут себя непредсказуемо. Ставьте руками. И mocha вроде как уже устарела...

Comment: на чем основано мнение, об устаревшести Мока и какие в такое случае варианты современно?

Comment: Вы правда думаете что я Вам сейчас тут целую статью напишу, потратив много времени, чтобы убедить Вас занять ту или иную позицию? Если бы информации было мало возможно я бы и объяснил разницу. Ну а так это именно тот случай, когда лучший ответ Вам даст гугл.